# Nokogiri selecting too much text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, nokogiri

Using Nokogiri and Ruby, I am trying to parse out a street address using a CSS selector. However, it is also including the city which I do not want.

Here is the statement I am using:

```
address = listing.at_css(".address").text
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="address">
  117/1 Main St ,
  <span class="green">
  <strong>
   <u>
    <a href="city">Chicago</a>
   </u>
  </strong>
  </span>
```

The result I want:

```
117/1 Main St
```

but the result I am getting:

```
117/1 Main St , Chicago \n
```

I was thinking of using regex in combination with Nokogiri, but I'm not sure if Ruby can cut everything out after `" ,"` including going back to cut out the `" , "`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns `117/1 Main St ,` (with space and comma):

```
listing.at_css(".address").child.text
```

And this returns `117/1 Main St` (space and comma removed):

```
listing.at_css(".address").child.text.sub(/ ,$/,"")
```

Comment: It's close but still not working. When I just try "hello , ".sub(/  ,$/,""), I get no change. If I do without the dollar sign, it turns it into "hello " which still has an extra space.

Comment: You have to add another space after the comma: `/ , $/`

Comment: Or perhaps better: `.sub(/[ ,]+$/,'')` (remove all trailing spaces and/or commas).